# Why is this program failing to output these strings in the Terminal?

Tags: c, macos

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age = 10;
    int height = 72;

    printf("I am %d years old.\n", age);
    printf("I am %d inches tall.\n", height);

    return 0;
}
```

I am following the learncthehardway book and everything is fine and dandy except that the make command outputs no errors but the program still does not print the strings. I just get the terminal command line prompt again after "make ex3"

What is happening? I triple checked every single character in the code and it is exactly the same as the one in the book, am I missing something?

OSX 10.9.2 if that even matters...

Comment: You seem to be using a make command, which is used to compile your code, not run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make` compiles your code.  It creates an executable, in this case, most  likely in the directory you ran the make command.  You need to run the result executable (probably called `ex3` or `a.out`) to get any output to the screen. Try: `./ex3` to run.  You need the `./` to tell it to look in the current directory for the executable, assuming that it isn not in your path... (which it normally would not be)

NOTE: the answer is in the book: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex3.html... specifically:

"**What You Should See**

When you do the whole build you should see something like this:

```
$ make ex3
cc -Wall -g    ex3.c   -o ex3
$ ./ex3
I am 10 years old.
I am 72 inches tall.
$
```

Pretty soon I'm going to stop telling you to run make and what the build looks like, so please make sure you're getting this right and that it's working."

Please read the book you are learning from.